# An "On Stop" method for python Threads

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

Me and a friend are having a programming challenge to who can make a good VOS (Virtual Operating System) and currently mine is running custom programs from Threads within the program, I am using Tkinter currently so the separate Threads have their own self.master.mainloop(). I have all the Threads stored in a list but I was wondering whether I could call a function in the Thread which would call a subroutine in the program telling it to do self.master.destroy(). Is there any way to do this?

I would like something along the lines of

```
class ToBeThread():
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()
        self.master.mainloop()
    def on_stop(self, reason):
        self.master.destroy()
```

Then in my main class

```
 from threading import Thread
 thread = Thread(ToBeThread())
 thread.setDaemon(True)
 thread.on_stop += ToBeThread.on_stop # Similar to how it is done in c#
 thread.start()
 ...

 ...
 thread.stop() # This calls the functions related to the "on_stop"
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as a solution. Just click the check mark left of it.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Sorry I was not aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do this, so for any wondering I did:

```
from threading import Thread

class MyThread(Thread):def __init__(self, method, delay=-1):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.method = method
    self._running = False
    self.delay = delay
    self.setDaemon(True)
def run(self):
    self._running = True
    while self._running == True:
        self.method()
        if self.delay != -1:
            time.sleep(self.delay)
def stop(self):
    self._running = False
```

This allows me to write pass a function in through the initialiser, and it will run it ever x seconds or as many times as possible until I do thread.stop()